# How thorough must a support website be for the iTunes AppStore?

Tags: itunes, appstore-approval

I'm currently submitting to the AppStore for the first time and am setting up a support site. Can it be as simple as a list of instructions and a support email? Or must I have full documentation, and accept user support tickets, etc.? The product in question is a very small, simple standalone app, so anything more than a simple informative landing page would be overkill.

All experience-based replies welcome. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it matters. For the first few months that my app was in the iOS App Store, i just had the support link go to a contact form on my site.

Comment: Good to note for future projects. For this one, I Ended up just making a landing page describing features, instructions, and requirements. Still awaiting approval with fingers x'ed!